# What is happening behind EF SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net

Assume that I have a domain object which has association with couple of other entities (ofcourse mapped to multiple tables). And I made changes in master and associated entities. Naturally EF has to update this in multiple tables on save.

Whether it be ObjectContext or DbContext, a call to SaveChanges() method will tell Entity Framework to "Saves all changes made in this context to the underlying database."

Could anyone tell me "What is happening behind SaveChanges()"?

Is all resulting sql statements INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE goes to database in one go as prepared statement?

or is EF doing back and forth with DB to execute the sql statement one by one?

Is there any configuration in EF to switch between this?

Comment: You can profile your database and see what exactly is going on

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to know?

Comment: You can use [Miniprofiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) to view the EF queries.

Comment: Kieren, you can write efficient code when you learn/understand what is happening behind scene. For example if there is some option for this I   would switch to prepared statement mode to improvise the performance while working with heavy transaction updates.

Comment: If you want to truly understand what is going on under the hood, I suggest you use a .NET decompiler to peer into the `System.Data.Entity` assembly.

Comment: I could do profiling/decompiling, still can anyone tell what is the actual method and is there any option to choose with?

Comment: @TMcManemy EF6 is open source at http://entityframework.codeplex.com/ so there is no need to decompile. Just clone the repo open in VS and browse, debug etc. SaveChanges() did not change a lot from EF5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment statements for CUD operations are not batched. We have a [work item](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/53) to fix this. Feel free to upvote

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, each modified **entity** will result in a roundtrip to the database (all bound by a single transaction). While I'm not aware of any configuration that will change this behavior, I won't say that there are not EF implementations out there that achieve this "batching" functionality. I just don't think they are available, out of the box.

Comment: It is a clear performance hit when you work with series of changes. Why EF team choosed roundtrip over prepared sql statement?